# WSO2: Listener to hook into SAML authentication flow

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Version: WSO2 Identity Server 5.4.1+

For audit purposes we wrote a UserOperationEventListener in order to hook into the authentication process by implementing doPostAuthenticate().

This captures API authentication and web login via form.
Unfortunately the listener is not called when IS operates as a SAML SP to another 3rd party SAML IDP.

Question: Is there a Listener which is called when a SAML authentication is successful? 
Or is there another way to hook into the authentication flow to an external IDP?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update in case anyone has the same requirements. We have now implemented an AuthenticationDataPublisher Listener which covers all session creation events. In addition with above UserOperationEventListener it covers:

- Resource Owner Password Credential authentication
- local authentication during code/implicit flows
- login via upstream federated authentication e.g. SAML, OIDC
- SOAP admin API authentication